# How to generate the quantile distribution of a numeric property with Elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

I am trying to generate a [quantile](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantile) distribution chart ([histogram](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Histogram)) for a numeric property stored within documents managed by [Elasticsearch](http://www.elasticsearch.org/). For example, I would define a number of quantiles like 20, and the chart would be a histogram with 20 bars. The left-most bar would show the average of the numeric property for the 5% (100/20) of all documents for which this property would be the lowest across the entire set of documents, the second bar would show the same for the next 5%, and so on...

Doing this for 4 quantiles would show quartiles. And for 100 quantiles, it would show every percentile.

I looked at the [histogram facet](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-facets-histogram-facet.html) and the [range facet](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-facets-range-facet.html), but neither of them seem to be applicable. In fact, I am suspecting that the histogram facet should be renamed in order to avoid any confusion. While I would really like to be able to generate this chart with a single query, doing one query per quantile would be acceptable for my current use case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With 0.90 and facets, you would have to use multiple search requests in order to calculate these quantiles.  No way around that unfortunately. However, you could reduce round trips by combining several search requests into a single request using [multi-search](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-multi-search.html).

The soon-to-be-released 1.0 has a new [aggregations](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.x/search-aggregations.html) framework which provides much more flexibility than facets.  Quantiles aren't in there yet, but an [estimated quantiles aggregation is in the works](https://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/commits/features/quantile_aggregations). Will hopefully make it in for 1.01, but no promises :)

Comment: That would address all my requirements. Thanks DrTech!